# await on a function that return an Observable

Tags: typescript, async-await, rxjs

I had the following bug in my Typescript code but can't understand how is that possible that I don't get any compile time or runtime error.

```
this.getApiClient().getStuffFromTheApi()
```

the `getStuffFromTheApi` returns an `Observable<Stuff[]>`.
Now when I call `await` on this method without `toPromise()` nothing happens.
Why are the compiler can't check for this and why are no runtime errors? How can I make the code more safe to find such bugs more easily?

EDIT:
declaration is
getStuffFromTheApi(): Observable {....}

Comment: Can you show how is that method declared?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there was a ts rule you could use "no await without promise" but I'm not sure (see if link works) I know the opposite doesn't work "no promise without await" because people do that all the time. Is there a case where people await non-promises? see https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/await-promise/

Answer (score 0):

The following code waits for the Observable response to be completed:

```
let response: Observable<any> = ...;
await response;
```

The following code waits for response and gives first value of a sequence:

```
let response: Observable<any> = ...;
await response.toPromise();
```

Method getStuffFromTheApi() could return an Observable that gives values and never completes.